# Admin can enter JavaScript - potential security risk?

Tags: comments, javascript, security

WP 3.5/TwentyTwelve/Clean install. I try this when login as admin and editor.

I try add reply for first post "Hello World":

```
<script>alert('XSS')</script><script><</script>
```

and get popup window

[image].

Is it porential security risk or can no care?
Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is in your question.

> I try this when login as admin and editor.

The roles have the [`unfiltered_html`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html) capability that allows them to put whatever HTML they choose, including `<script>` tags, where ever they choose.

Is is a security risk?  Only if you give folks you don't trust admin and/or editor roles. Or someone gains access to your an admin/editor account. Or there's another security hole somewhere in the core that allows privilege escalation from a lower to higher user level (unlikely).

By itself, it's not a security risk.  Admin and editors need to be able to do things to actually manage the site.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much! I accidentally added the line and a little scared when I saw the result :)